# Embed Instagram Post in Flutter

Tags: flutter, instagram

I'm looking for some packages which are doing like this https://github.com/Kobidl/react-native-embed-instagram in React Native

Is there any method to embed instagram post in Flutter? Like given a instagram link eg. https://www.instagram.com/p/BzNbnJXBe8m/

Comment: Show your work/research on this project.

Comment: @Alok it's like embedding instagram post in website using embed code but now it's not on website. It's on mobile which developed by Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use this lib to show embeded html 
 https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html_view